# Explain why: $(1+\sin x+\cos x)^2=2(1+\cos x)(1+\sin x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

How can I prove that: $$(1+\sin x+\cos x)^2=2(1+\cos x)(1+\sin x)$$
I've started like this:
$$(1+\sin x+\cos x)^2=((1+\sin x)+\cos x)^2=(1+\sin x)^2+\cos^2x+2(1+\sin x)\cos x$$

Comment: You can prove any polynomial identity in $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ mechanically by substituting $\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$  and $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and simplifying. Here the $t$ is $\tan(x/2)$. With this technique these problems about proving trigonometric identities will not bother you any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue expanding like you have, to obtain $$1 + \sin^2(x) + 2\sin(x) + \cos^2(x) + 2\cos(x) + 2\sin(x)\cos(x),$$ which then beomes $$2 + 2\sin(x) + 2\cos(x) + 2\sin(x)\cos(x).$$ From there, factor out the two and notice that $1 + a + b + ab = (1+a)(1+b)$.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your goal, you want to factor out $(1+\sin x)$:

$(1+\sin x)^2+\cos^2x+2(1+\sin x)\cos x=$

$(1+\sin x)^2 + (1-\sin^2x)+2(1+\sin x)\cos x=$

$\big[(1+\sin x)+(1-\sin x)+2\cos x\big](1+\sin x)=$

$[2+2\cos x](1+\sin x)=2(1+\cos x)(1+\sin x).$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{aligned}
(1+\sin x+\cos x)^{2}=& 1+\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{2} x+2 \sin x+2 \cos x \\
&+2 \sin x \cos x \\
=& 2+2 \sin x+2 \cos x+2 \sin x \cos x \\
=& 2(1+\sin x)(1+\cos x) .
\end{aligned}